# DV01 on IRS giving error in Quantlib for ZAR curve "1st iteration: failed at 14th alive instrument"

Tags: quantlib, interest-rate-swap, quants

I am at my wits end to calcualte the DV01 of a swap but keep getting the error "RuntimeError: 1st iteration: failed at 14th alive instrument, pillar May 28th, 2024, maturity May 28th, 2024, reference date June 1st, 2021: 2nd leg: negative time (-0.0109589) given" I have deposit, fra and swap rate and have create separate helpers for them. Can someone please help?
This maturity is the first maturity for the swap quotes.

````
from QuantLib import *

# global data
from QuantLib import RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle#

calendar = TARGET()
todaysDate = Date(28, May, 2021)
Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todaysDate
settlementDate = calendar.advance(todaysDate, 2, Days)
maturity = Date(15, September, 2026)
tenor = maturity.year() - settlementDate.year()

# market quotes
deposits = {
    (3, Months): 0.0368300,

}

swaps = {
    (3, Years): 0.0495000,
    (4, Years): 0.0541500,
    (5, Years): 0.0584500,
    (6, Years): 0.0624500,
    (7, Years): 0.0659200,
    (8, Years): 0.0688500,
    (9, Years): 0.0714200,
    (10, Years): 0.0736000,
    (12, Years): 0.0773500,
    (15, Years): 0.0809500,
    (20, Years): 0.0837000,
    (25, Years): 0.0850000,
    (30, Years): 0.0855000}

fra = {
    (4, Months): 0.0371500,
    (5, Months): 0.0375500,
    (6, Months): 0.0378000,
    (7, Months): 0.0388000,
    (8, Months): 0.0390500,
    (9, Months): 0.0404500,
    (10, Months): 0.0409000,
    (11, Months): 0.0425000,
    (12, Months): 0.0430000,
    (15, Months): 0.0463000,
    (18, Months): 0.0485000,
    (21, Months): 0.0517000,
    (24, Months): 0.0541000

}

# convert them to Quote objects
for n, unit in deposits.keys():
    deposits[(n, unit)] = SimpleQuote(deposits[(n, unit)])
for n, unit in swaps.keys():
    swaps[(n, unit)] = SimpleQuote(swaps[(n, unit)])
for n, unit in fra.keys():
    fra[(n, unit)] = SimpleQuote(fra[(n, unit)])

# build rate helpers

dayCounter = Actual365Fixed()  # day counter
bus_adjus = ModifiedFollowing
settlementDays = 2
depositHelpers = [DepositRateHelper(QuoteHandle(deposits[(n, unit)]),
                                    Period(n, unit), settlementDays,
                                    calendar, bus_adjus,  # business adjusted
                                    False, dayCounter)
                  for n, unit in deposits.keys()]

fixedLegFrequency = Quarterly
fixedLegTenor = Period(tenor, Years)
fixedLegAdjustment = bus_adjus
fixedLegDayCounter = dayCounter
floatingLegTenor = Period(tenor, Years)
floatingLegAdjustment = bus_adjus

# term structure handles

discountTermStructure = RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()
forecastTermStructure: RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle = RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()

# create index
underlying_index = Jibar(Period(3, Months), forecastTermStructure)

swapHelpers = [SwapRateHelper(QuoteHandle(swaps[(n, unit)]),
                              Period(n, unit), calendar,
                              fixedLegFrequency, fixedLegAdjustment,
                              fixedLegDayCounter, underlying_index)
               for n, unit in swaps.keys()]

fraHelpers = [FraRateHelper(QuoteHandle(fra[(n, unit)]),
                            n, underlying_index)
              for n, unit in fra.keys()]

fwd_start_date = Date(15, September, 2021)  # Effective_Date

# term-structure construction

helpers = depositHelpers + fraHelpers + swapHelpers
depoSwapCurve = PiecewiseLinearForward(settlementDate, helpers, dayCounter)

swapEngine = DiscountingSwapEngine(discountTermStructure)
# 5Y Swap

nominal = 10000000
fixedRate = 0.05
spread = 0.0

# using fwd date as pricing in the future
fixedSchedule = Schedule(fwd_start_date, maturity,
                         fixedLegTenor, calendar,
                         fixedLegAdjustment, fixedLegAdjustment,
                         DateGeneration.Backward, False)
floatingSchedule = Schedule(fwd_start_date, maturity,
                            floatingLegTenor, calendar,
                            floatingLegAdjustment, floatingLegAdjustment,
                            DateGeneration.Backward, False)

swap = VanillaSwap(VanillaSwap.Receiver, nominal,
                   fixedSchedule, fixedRate, fixedLegDayCounter,
                   floatingSchedule, underlying_index, spread,
                   dayCounter)
swap.setPricingEngine(swapEngine)

discountTermStructure.linkTo(depoSwapCurve)
forecastTermStructure.linkTo(depoSwapCurve)
print('NPV')
print(swap.NPV())
# Get the correct fair rate and create the vanilla swap again with the right rate
fixedRate = swap.fairRate()
swap = VanillaSwap(VanillaSwap.Receiver, nominal,
                   fixedSchedule, fixedRate, fixedLegDayCounter,
                   floatingSchedule, underlying_index, spread,
                   dayCounter)
swap.setPricingEngine(swapEngine)

discountTermStructure.linkTo(depoSwapCurve)
forecastTermStructure.linkTo(depoSwapCurve)
print('NPV')
print(swap.NPV())
print('Rate')
print(swap.fairRate() * 100)

shift = 0.0001

temp_fyc_handle = YieldTermStructureHandle(depoSwapCurve)
temp_dyc_handle = YieldTermStructureHandle(depoSwapCurve)
shiftedForwardCurve = ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(temp_fyc_handle, QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(shift)))
shiftedDiscountCurve = ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(temp_dyc_handle, QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(shift)))
discountTermStructure.linkTo(shiftedDiscountCurve)
forecastTermStructure.linkTo(shiftedForwardCurve)
P_p = swap.NPV()

temp_fyc_handle = YieldTermStructureHandle(depoSwapCurve)
temp_dyc_handle = YieldTermStructureHandle(depoSwapCurve)
shiftedForwardCurve = ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(temp_fyc_handle, QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(-shift)))
shiftedDiscountCurve = ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(temp_dyc_handle, QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(-shift)))
discountTermStructure.linkTo(shiftedDiscountCurve)
forecastTermStructure.linkTo(shiftedForwardCurve)
P_m = swap.NPV()

dv01 = (P_m - P_p) / 2.0
print('Swap DV01')
print(dv01)

```
````

Comment: Just one comment on this. If I use ```underlying_index = IborIndex('JIBAR', Period(3, Months), 2, ZARCurrency(), SouthAfrica(), bus_adjust, False, dayCounter, forecastTermStructure)``` instead of ```underlying_index = Jibar(Period(3, Months), forecastTermStructure)```
it works